# alpha blending in gtk

Tags: graphics, gtk, pygtk

How can you draw semi-transparent [primitives such as filled polygons](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gdkdrawable.html#method-gdkdrawable--draw-polygon) to a Drawable in GTK?

Its 2010, and I google isn't finding how to put an alpha value into a colour for me.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `gtk.gdk.Drawable.cairo_create()` and operate on the returned `gtk.gdk.CairoContext`.  See [documentation](http://cairographics.org/documentation/pycairo/2/reference/context.html).  Cairo is a generic vector 2D library that is used in GTK+ since many versions ago; GDK drawing primitives are deprecated in its favor (though not the whole GDK).

Answer (score 2):

Here is actual source code to do it. I just wanted to gray out the entire pixbuf, but to do a shape you'd just have to use the appropriate path methods:

```
def getBlendedPixbuf(pixbuf, (r,g,b,a)):
    """Turn a pixbuf into a blended version of the pixbuf by drawing a
    transparent alpha blend on it."""
    pixbuf = pixbuf.copy()
    #convert pixbuf to Drawable:
    visual = gtk.gdk.visual_get_best()
    screen = visual.get_screen()
    cmap = screen.get_default_colormap()

    w,h = pixbuf.get_width(), pixbuf.get_height()
    drawable = gtk.gdk.Pixmap(
        None, w, h, visual.depth)
    gc = drawable.new_gc()
    drawable.draw_pixbuf(
        gc, pixbuf, 0,0,0,0,-1,-1)

    #do all the drawing on it
    cc = drawable.cairo_create()
    cc.set_source_rgba(r,g,b,a)
    cc.paint()

    #put it back into a pixbhf
    pixbuf.get_from_drawable(
        drawable,cmap,0,0,0,0,w,h)
    return pixbuf
```