# gtk.gdk: make image 50% grayer

Tags: python, pygtk, gtk, gdk

I have an image wiht `gtk.gdk`. I want to make it look grayed out, so I wanna do something like draw a gray rectangle over it with 50% alpha value. How would I do this? The docs are so confusing.

Comment: Ah [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3048148/alpha-blending-in-gtk) has the answer. it's just that the pygtk documentation is not complete. i'll post code on how exactly to do it, though, since i feel that will help someone. or ill post it as an answer to that answer, so no duplicates.

Comment: You could also reduce the brightness of each channel in the image by half.

Comment: @Dana the Sane: That would only makje the image darker, not grayer. For grayer, one has to average each pixel component with 0.5 (or 128)

Comment: Was this solved? If so, an answer needs to be posted.

Answer (score 0):

i just thought of a way
taking half of the color's highest values and taking half of the number directly between them and putting that on the lowest number (Eg: 0,255,255 to 127,255,255 or 0,127,255 to 96,127,255) 
or taking the second highest number and the highest number, finding the 50%, putting that as the second highest number, then doing that again for the absolute lowest number (Eg: 0,128,255 > 112,192,255)
hope this works for me and for you, right now im recommending to myself and you, the second option, however if you're lazy, the first option is less work